# QField : Attribute form not displaying correctly

Tags: attribute-table, qfield, attribute-form

I'm a student in the end of class internship and just found out about QField. I'm familiar with GIS so I didn't think I'd struggle so hard.
I want to use QField for butterfly conservation, and will use QField to work with volunteers who will help with the sampling of this butterfly.

I wanted to try it out and test how it works, so I followed this link found on qgis.org : https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/training_overview.html

I followed it strictly as it seems to provide a good overview. But as I opened my project in QField, I was able to put points on the map, but unable to fill out the form as it is plain blank.

[image: Blank attribute form appearing on Qfield when I input data]

Here's the attribute form of my project on Qgis 3.22. I have followed the guide linked in the beginning of this post so the other entries have the same options.
[image: Attribute Form on Qgis 3.22]

Here's the Data sources of my project,
[image: Data sources of my project]

I've tried with different setting, differents types of layer (polygon, points, line...) The points appears on the project but I cannot fill the form, so the points are kind of useless

I am still new to the GIS world. I have not found this issue elsewhere so I don't know if it may be some mistake of my side.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the short [Tour].

Comment: What does the widget look like for the field (Layer Properties - Attributes Form)?

Comment: @BERA I have added the attribute form from Qgis 3.22 for this project,

Comment: Should work. The layer isnt "Read only" under Project Properties - Data sources right?

Comment: @BERA The box isn't ticked, I have put a screenshot of the Data sources Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found an answer. I always tried to use the "Package for Qfield option" in the Qfield Extension but it never worked. I tried to directly import my project in .qgs and the Geopackage associated by drag and drop unto my device and it worked, I could fill the attribute form. To synchronize back into Qgis, I simply did it in a reverse order. I dragged the .qgs and the geopackage from my device to qgis and it synchronized too.
I still don't know what the issue is but I managed to bypass it by not using the extension.